# NodeJS & ReactJS: FormData is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, form-data

hello i am trying to send data to server but it does not works and returns undefined

here is what i have tried

CLIENT:

```
var Data = new FormData();
    Data.append('name', this.state.name);
    Data.append('time', this.state.time);
    Data.append('portion', this.state.portion);
    Data.append('method', this.state.method);
    Data.append('tags', JSON.stringify(this.state.tags));
    Data.append('ingredients', JSON.stringify(this.state.ingredients))
    Data.append('level', this.state.level)
console.log(Data)
axios.post('/api/post-recipe', Data)
 .then(res => res.data)
 .then(data =>{
      console.log(data.dish)
 })
 .catch(err => {
    if(err.response){
        if(err.response.data.redirect === true){
            window.location.replace(err.response.data.location)
        }
        if(err.response.data.message){
        alert(err.response.data.message)
        }
    }
 })
```

SERVER:

```
  router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const {
             name,
             time,
             portion,
             ingredients,
             method,
             level,
             tags
                 } = req.body

console.log(name + time + portion + ingredients + method + level + tags)

} catch (error) {
 return res.status(500).send({
  message: error.message
   })
  }
})
```

and it logs NaN in console and if i add words in console like `'name: ' name` and etc. it logs undefined values, i have installed form-data from npm and i am importing it to my code and i can not get what is problem

Comment: What is that router? Are you using Express.JS? What body parsers are you using?

Comment: yes express JS, as i know hapi js routing is different from express and, if you meant my body parser configuration i have done it perfectly  because in other pages it works

Comment: "Works on other pages" often means "Is wrong for the circumstances of *this* page". Provide a [mcve]./

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
app.use(bodyParser.json())

Comment: Yup, your body parser is wrong.

Comment: what? but why do you think that

Comment: in my old web application i used this config and successfully uploaded files and it worked

Comment: oh sorry, i thought you was talking about 'body-parser' module, i use multer

Comment: You have not managed to do this yet: "Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem in the question itself", but you have reached the point of name calling. I'm out of here.

Answer (score 0):

1. You seem to be posting data to `/api/post-recipe/` but looking for it on route `/`
2. You are logging to console the result of the mathematical sum of your variables - log them individually or read further [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: i said when i log individually it returns undefined values, and i have route configurations `router.use('/api/post-recipe', require('file'))`

Answer (score 0):

The route you send your data to (`/api/post-recipe`) does not match the route on the server (`/`) where you handle it. You either have to change the call to `axios` in the client, or you have to adjust the route definition on the server to match `/api/post-recipe`.

Additionally, you try to concatenate the individual strings with `+`, but this does not necessarily work. Try

```
console.log(name, time, ...);
```

instead and put in the other variables for `...`. If you also would like to know the variables' names, and not just their values, encapsulate all the parameters to `console.log` in a pair of curly braces:

```
console.log({ name, time, ... });
```

This turns the parameters into an object, and will also show their names.

Comment: i said when i log individually it returns undefined values, and i have route configurations router.use('/api/post-recipe', require('file'))